# How to run Powershell file (having extension .ps1) using jmeter?

Tags: powershell, groovy, jmeter, beanshell

[image: I am using OS sampler in this image]

I want to execute .ps1 file in jmeter. I have pass the parameter as in image,but in output facing errors.`The filename, directory name, or volume label syntax is incorrect.`
 Though the filename, directory name are correct.

Answer (score 1):

Here is your problem:

[image: JMeter Powershell]

Remove that quotation mark and everything should start working as expected

In general, you are making things overcomplicated.

1. Why do you need these `cmd /c`? Why just don't call `powershell` directly?
2. Normally powershell is in Windows PATH, there is no need to provide full path to it

So configure your OS Process Sampler as:

- Command: `powershell`
- Parameter: `D:\Software\apache=jmeter-3.0\apache-jmeter-3.0\bin\TIP.ps1`

[image: JMeter good os process sampler configuration]

See [How to Run External Commands and Programs Locally and Remotely from JMeter](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/how-run-external-commands-and-programs-locally-and-remotely-jmeter) article for more information on invoking 3rd-party processes from your JMeter test.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is an old thread but since the response was not correct for me I found the solution to be this:

Using the **OS Process Sampler** you need to add as command **powershell.exe** and as variables exactly the following:

- -executionpolicy
- bypass
- -file
- fullpathToYourScript.ps1

[image: Jmeter Call Powershell Sample]

This worked perfectly fine for me.